# Moving an element to the top of the container in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to move the "About me" header up to the top of the section as it's    currently stuck in the middle.

Also my second paragraph has joined onto the same line as my first paragraph.

One "weird" thing to me is that if I just remove the "about" id then the layout is completely fixed and perfect how I want it, but I'm trying to learn flexbox, so I don't really want to go down that route, unless I have to.

```css
#about {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.aboutme {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  padding-top: 25px;
  order: 1;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.profile-photo {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 20px;
  order: 0;
  max-width: 700px;
  max-height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
p {
  order: 2;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  color: #000
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section id="about">
    <img src="img/meprofile.jpg" alt="Photograph of" class="profile-photo">
    <h2 class="aboutme">About me</h2>
    <p>Hello!.</p>
    <p>Check</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch from `flex-direction: row` to `column`.

In `column` mode the elements stack, just like in standard block layout, which is the reason why your layout is "fixed" when you disable the `#about` CSS rules.

When that happens, `display: flex` and `flex-flow: row` are disabled, and the elements stack vertically in standard block layout.

```css
#about {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.aboutme {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
.profile-photo {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50vw;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#about > div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  color: #000
}
body {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <h2 class="aboutme">About me</h2>
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/JV8yEjp.png" alt="Photograph of" class="profile-photo">
    <div>
      <p>Tart donut marzipan croissant sugar plum gummi bears apple pie. Wafer chocolate cake chupa chups macaroon danish topping. Bear claw gingerbread caramels chocolate bar chocolate marshmallow tart. Liquorice powder dessert.</p>
      <p>Wafer lemon drops tootsie roll halvah powder chupa chups apple pie. Sweet roll chocolate bar fruitcake chocolate biscuit gummi bears.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fy0ydmfg/5/)

Comment: I'd consider this a more useful answer if you mentioned what changes you made. It's just easier than comparing them. But good work still.

Comment: Good suggestion. Explanation added. Thanks. @oxwilder